# If Map contains key return value, otherwise return 0

Tags: dictionary, f#

I am new to F# and wanna do as the title says, but I keep getting these type errors.

I know this works:

```
> let rec validString2 =
  function
  | a -> Map.find a
> validString2 "x" (Map.ofList [("x", 5)]);;
>val it: int = 5
```

But I wanna return `Map.find a` **only** if `a` is in the map, otherwist I wanna return 0. When I try this:

```
let rec validString =
  function
  | a -> if (Map.containsKey a) then Map.find a else 0
```

The errors message I get (and red underline under `Map.containsKey a`):

```
This expression was expected to have type
    'bool'    
but here has type
    'Map<'a,'b> -> bool'
```

The same happens if I tried:

```
let validString =
  function
  | Some x -> x
  | None -> 0

let rec evalValidString =
  function
  | V a -> validString (Map.tryFind a)
```

It seems I'm misunderstanding how types with maps work. I don't understand how bool is different from Map<'a, 'b> -> bool. The map function returns a bool, I should be able to evaluate it.

Comment: When you write `Map.containsKey a`, which map do you mean to look inside of?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Well my input would look like 
`validString "x" (Map.ofList [("x", 5)])` and I'd like it to return 5 (or 0 if it does not exist in the map)

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Let me try again. When you call the `Map.containsKey` function, how does it know in which map to look up the key?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Well as I've understood F# can pattern match it.

An example that works:
`let rec validString2 =
  function
  | a -> Map.find a`

`validString2 "x" (Map.ofList [("x", 5)]) ;;
val it: int = 5`

Comment: That's not in the code in your question. I think you need to update the code to match your comment.

Comment: Code can sometimes, not always, be easier to understand if, instead of using `function` and an implicit parameter, an explicit parameter is declared. (edit: An answer doing exactly that was written while I wrote this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you have to specify the map you want to search. In the function below, I've named it `myMap`:

```ml
let myLookup (key : string) myMap =
    myMap
        |> Map.tryFind key         // does the key exist in myMap?
        |> Option.defaultValue 0   // if not, return 0
```

Note that `myMap` is a value of type `Map<string, int>`. You could then use this function as follows:

```ml
let aMap = Map.ofList [("x", 5)]
let xValue = myLookup "x" aMap
let yValue = myLookup "y" aMap
printfn "%A" (xValue, yValue)   // 5, 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved my problem and I learned something new. Kudos to you :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question already has an accepted answer but I think some further additional comments might also add to your learning of F#:

```ml
let rec validString2 =
    function
    | a -> Map.find a

validString2 "x" (Map.ofList [("x", 5)]);;

val it: int = 5
```

1. The `rec` means this is a recursive function, yet there is *no* call to `validString` in the body. It is not a recursive function so no `rec` needed:

```ml
  let validString2' = function | a -> Map.find a
```

2. Now using function is a pattern match which makes the last argument to `validString2` implicit. Can making this explicit with `match` help here?

```ml
  let validString2'' a = match a with a -> Map.find a
```

3. Yes! Since, whatever it is, is matched in`a`, hence there is only *one* branch needed. That is, there is no need for pattern matching at all:

```ml
  let validString2''' a = Map.find a
```

3. But `Map.find` takes *two* arguments but has only one (`a`) here. So `validString2` is a *partially applied* function, still awaiting a second argument, the actual map to find `a` in. This explains the error in `validString` since both `Map.contains` and `Map.find` both need a second argument and, as partially applied functions, they have type signatures `'Map<'a,'b> -> bool'`(`Map.contains k`) and `'Map<'a,'b> -> 'b`(`Map.find k` it does not know yet that 'b is an `int`) respectively. Hence your error message.
4. Finally, you can evolve your original solution to become:

```ml
  let validString' k m = if Map.contains k m then Map.find k m else 0
```

So no need for pattern matching or partially applied functions in this case but hopefully this helps you understand these in future uses.

UPDATE:

5. Solution (4) requires two passes over the data, the first for `Map.contains` - `O(log(N))` - and the second for `Map.find` - also `O(log(N))` . Can we make it a single pass?

```ml
  let validString'' k m = if Map.contains k m then m[k] else 0
```

6. However both operations are still `O(log(N))`, since`m[k]` is *not* `O(1)`, so this is *still* `2*O(log(N))`. Can we do better than that? This is where you look at the `try...` collection function variants. In this case you need `map.tryFind` which returns an Option, with either `Some value` or `None` - if the key does not exist. And this is a *single pass* `O(log(N))` solution:

```ml
    let validString''' k m = 
        match Map.tryFind k m with
        | Some v -> v 
        | None -> 0
```

7. This pattern match expression has its own collection function `Option.defaultValue` and this leads to the solution presented in the previous and marked correct answer.